# Spring Config Server - customize http client

Tags: spring-cloud-config, apache-httpasyncclient

I using Spring Config Server with git repo. I want add interceptor to standart http client, which connect to git. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

What spring config server is doing is normal request/response cycle. using internal endpoints.

so normal Spring MVC HandlerInterceptor could do the job for you.
detailed walk-through can be found here:
[HandlerInterceptor](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor)